# Tensorflow, convolution with custom filters

Tags: tensorflow

I have two tensors, A and B.

A represents a tensor with dimensions of N x H x W x 512. 
More specifically, A is an output from convolutional layers. N is the batch size. H and W is the height and the width of the tensor, A. 512 is the number of channels of the tensor, A.

B represents a tensor with dimensions of N x 1 x 1 x 512 x 256. 
More specifically, it is N number of kernels of a convolutional layer and each kernel has dimensions of 1 x 1 x 512 x 256. Here, 512 and 256 refer input channels and output channels, respectively.

What I want to do is to convolve each kernel with the tensor, A, such as

```
all_out = []
For i in range(N):
     kernel = B[i]
     a_batch = A[i]
     a_out = conv2d(a_batch, kernel, trainable=False) #pseudo convolution function as tf.nn.conv2d does not accept trainable argument.
     all_out.append(a_out)
all_out = some_func(all_out) # convert to N x H x W x 256 tensor
```

I've tried with tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d after reshaping the two tensors, A and B. But, it is slow and takes too much memory space.

Is there an efficient way to do this? Any suggestions?